# Make Logback print logs to a file

Tags: java, logging, logback, ktor

I have a Ktor server application and I want the output of the logs a in a file, this is my configuration of logback.xml:

> ```
> <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
>     <encoder>
>         <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
>
> <appender name="rollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>         <fileNamePattern>logs/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
>         <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
>         <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
>     </rollingPolicy>
>     <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
>         <maxFileSize>3MB</maxFileSize>
>     </triggeringPolicy>
>     <encoder>
>         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
>
> <root level="info">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
>     <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
> </root>
>
> <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO"/>
> <logger name="io.netty" level="INFO"/> </configuration>
> ```

When I run the server with **java -jar server.jar** everything works OK and the log is written to the file. The /logs folder has 0777 permissions, so everyone can access and write to it.

The problem comes when I run the server in dettached mode with **nohup java -jar server.jar &**, with that, the server is not writting to the file.

Any ideas?